# PyPDF2 to extract vertical text from scanned pdf

Tags: python, python-3.x, pypdf, pdfminer, pdf-extraction

I am trying to extract text from the scanned pdf using PyPDF2. Some of the pdf contains text aligned vertically. But the orientation of the page is Portrait. Is there any way to identify if the text is vertically aligned and read vertical lines in PDF using pdfminer or PyPDF2

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to do this with PyPDF2 at the moment (I'm the maintainer of PyPDF2).

See also: https://github.com/py-pdf/PyPDF2/issues/1071